# Is there a special function defined for this integral?

Tags: integration

Recently, I came across this integral: 
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{xe^{-sx}}{1-e^{-px}}dx$$
where $s, p$ are, in general, complex constants.

As far as I know, this integral does not have an elementary form. However, this integral looks so neat and simple that I guess a special function is defined for this- just like the Gamma function.

Is there such a special function? If so, have its properties been studied extensively?

p.s. Some might say the integral is simply the Laplace transform of $\frac{x}{1-e^{-px}}$. Well, if that’s the best answer, I would be a little bit disappointed.

Thanks for any help in advance.

EDIT: I realized I missed a $x$ in the numerator. Sorry for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\operatorname{Re}(s) > 0$ and $\operatorname{Re}(p) > 0$, we have

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x e^{-sx}}{1 - e^{-px}} \, dx
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-(s+np)x} \, dx
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(s+np)^2}
= \frac{1}{p^2}\psi'\left(\frac{s}{p}\right) $$

where $\psi$ is the [*digamma function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) (and hence $\psi'$ is the [*trigamma function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function)). Alternatively,

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x e^{-sx}}{1 - e^{-px}} \, dx
= \frac{1}{p^2}\zeta\left(2,\frac{s}{p}\right) $$

where $\zeta(s, z)$ is the [*Hurwitz zeta function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function).

Comment: Maple yields this also: $$\frac{1}{p^2}\Psi^{(1)}\left(\frac{s}{p}\right)$$

Comment: Could you please check: when $\operatorname{Re}(p)<0$, does the integral equal $-\frac{1}{p^2}\psi ’\left(1-\frac{s}{p}\right)$?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's called "$\infty$":
$$\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-sx}\mathrm{d}x}{1-\mathrm{e}^{-px}}\sim\frac{1}{p}\ln\frac{1}{\epsilon}$$
because the integrand diverges as $\frac{1}{px}$ as $x\to 0^+$.

On the other hand, if you subtract out this divergent part, you'll probably get something like the [digamma function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.2#E2):

$$\psi\left(z\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^{-t}}{t}-\frac{e^{-zt}}{1-e^%
{-t}}\right)\mathrm{d}t\quad (\Re z>0)$$

(DLMF [5.9.12](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9#E12)).

Comment: I’ve made a mistake in my question and now it is corrected. Would you like to update your answer?

Answer (score 0):

HINT, the hypergeometric function :
$$\int \frac{e^{-sx}}{1-e^{-px}}dx=\frac{1}{s-p}e^{x(p-s)}\:_2F_1\left(1\:,\:1-\frac{s}{p}\:;\:2-\frac{s}{p}\:;\:e^{px} \right)+\text{constant}$$

Comment: I’ve made a mistake in my question and now it is corrected. Would you like to update your answer?